# Alt+F2 doesn't run scripts from a folder added to PATH, but terminal does run it

Tags: scripts, gnome-terminal, environment-variables, zsh

I used to run scripts using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> in Ubuntu 18.04, but they don't run in Ubuntu 22.04. However, they run properly if I run them from the terminal which uses `zsh`.

To modify the `PATH` variable I opened the `~/.zshrc` file in VSCode and added:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

I then used:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

My system's specs:

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- GNOME Version: 42.9
- Windowing System: Wayland

Answer (score 3):

It depends on at what level you added the directory to your path:

1. Systemwide, i.e., applicable for all users?
2. Applicable when you log in?
3. Applicable when you open a terminal?

Only in cases (1) and (2) will the changed PATH also have effect for the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run prompt.

You mention that you changed your `PATH` in the `~/.zshrc` file. That configuration file is read each time you open an interactive terminal, so you are in case (3).

To have your changed PATH also in effect when using the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> run prompt, make the change in your `~/.profile` file instead. That file is read when you log in as a user (case (2)).

Comment: thanks for explanation,but i found these lines at .profile  # set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists  
`if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ;  then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"  
fi`

Comment: @leegenny: So it ought to work. Did you relogin/reboot after having created the `~/bin` directory? Which display manager do you use?